# C# representing binary data in 2d graph?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, and after some months spend on it, I'm trying to put together a project.

I have hex files and binary files from ECU of Cars. What I want to do is to view that data in a 2d graph with lines.

For example I have an array `{ 0x41, 0x31, 0x33, 0x44, 0x54, 0x45 }`, and I'd like to make a 2d viewer to show this array in a graph as follows - the view in the graph is in 16 bit:

[image: Graph of array 16 bit]

Which tool or framework or guide I can use to understand how do it?

Comment: Note: the computer doesn't really have a notion of hex vs decimal vs octal vs binary etc; they're just numbers (0x41 is 65, 0x32 is 49, etc). So the only question here is: how do display a chart from some numbers. OK; so what UI technology are you using here? Is this web? Winforms? WPF? Unity? Consolel/terminal? Something else?

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm using winforms for my application, you get it right, how I can display numbers in a chart?

Comment: maybe start here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart?view=netframework-4.8 note there are a range of 3rd party controls for charting